# Remainder when $333^{333}$ is divided by $7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, integers

Find the Remainder when $333^{333}$ is divided by $7$

I think I have to find $333^{333}\equiv r \pmod7$ where $r(\ge0)$ is the remainder but how do I get in that form

Comment: First., do you know what $333\pmod{7}$ is?

Comment: @JMoravitz yes I know

Comment: You should include what you know (*or think you know*) it is, and what you know about its order.

Comment: @John757  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

Note that by FLT

$$333^6\equiv 1 \mod 7$$

thus

$$333^{333}\equiv 333^{3}\equiv 4^{3} \mod 7$$

Answer (score 2):

$$333\equiv2^2\pmod7$$

and$$333\equiv3\pmod{\phi(7)}$$

$$\implies333^{333}\equiv(2^2)^3\equiv?\pmod7$$

Answer (score 2):

$$333^{333}=(336-3)^{333}\equiv(-3)^{333}=-27^{111}\equiv-(-1)^{111}=1.$$